# How should I model a situation when a user has a variable number of options to pick from, and one option requires additional data to be collected?

Tags: database-design

I'm trying to model a situation where a user is presented with any combination of 3 options (A, B, or C) (at least one), and is expected to select one available option. But if option C is selected an extra parameter is collected. There is not a M2M relationship between the form and options, they are created together.

I'm trying to come up with a way to enforce the rule that option C cannot be selected if the extra field is not supplied, but the best I can come up with is a check constraint.

I also thought about an enum on Form for either A, B, or C but then I loose the FK constraint to ensure the Option X record exists. I'm not sure which is best or if a better option exists. Another thing I have to keep in mind is that options may be added in the future, but not likely ever removed.

[image: ERD]

Comment: Is there a specific reason you need to this at the database layer instead of application one? Take note with the coupling this tight any changes to the form on the frontend will require a migration on the database.

Comment: I guess it isn't really required. But in that case I'm still not really sure what the apropriate schema would look like.

Comment: Well you can completely get rid of `form` columns for a start and just have the table as `(id bigint GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, user_id uuid NOT NULL, foo int, bar text, baz boolean, extra text )`. The conditional logic you described can be handled by the app before inserting/updating and the presentation of the inserted data can be handled by the frontend afterwards.

Comment: I think that's a start, but `extra` is collected as part of the user's answer. It isn't known when the form is created. The answer table would have id, user, form, extra, and an enum for option maybe?

Comment: The form is created where? Form is just a representation of data and has no relevance to the database layer. So whatever form data arrives, the application layer is free to transform it according to arbitrary rules as long as insertion is valid. Depending on the wording you either reject the input with `extra` but without `baz` or fetch an `extra` value with `baz` present and then insert the final result.

Comment: I'll try to explain the application a bit better. A user comes to our site and creates a `form` and chooses any combination of options A, B, and C (at least one, including option-specific fields). Then many users may visit the form and answer by picking one of the options presented by the form (A, B, or C). If C is chosen the `extra` field is collected as part of their answer.

Comment: Custom form builders are tricky, but I don't think this logic belongs in the database layer still. At the very least you'd need a `form_templates` table which would look like `(id PK, user_id uuid, type text, data json )` where `type` would act as a discriminator key for a discriminated union of the `data` shapes. The answers can be stored as `(id PK, user_id uuid, template_id FK, data json)`. This way you won't need to code specific logic in the database, and the app along with frontend would know how to handle it by knowing template ID and therefore its type.